# angular routing, current route buttons/functions unresponsive after directing from default route

Tags: angularjs

Keeping it short, its a single page application so index.php are first loaded with the default template URL and controller. When I click a button and move to a new route ( new templateUrl and controller), nothing in that page works, clicking the cancel button doesn't popup an alert or redirect me to the main page.

Basically
main page: list sales page (url#1 controller#1) -> click add sales -> add sales page (url#2 controller2) > buttons doesnt work

**Routing**

```
var app = angular.module("phpApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/",{
    templateUrl:"view-list.php", controller: "listController"
})
    .when("/add", {
    templateUrl:"view-details.php", controller:"addController"
})
.when("/:index",{
    templateUrl:"view-details.php", controller:"editController"
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo:"/"
});
}]);
```

**default templateURL** (pretend the main index page only has 1 button which is "Add Sales")

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button data-ng-click="addSales()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Sales</button>
</div>
```

**default controller**

```
app.controller('listController', ['$scope', '$location','$routeParams', 'salesService', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, salesService){
$scope.data = salesService.getSales();

$scope.addSales = function(){
    $location.path('/add');
};

$scope.editSales = function(x)
{
    $location.path("/" + x);
};

$scope.delSales = function(x)
{
    if (confirm('Are you sure to delete?'))
    {
         alert("deleted item asdasd");
        //var index = $scope.bdays.indexOf(item);
        //$scope.bdays.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $location.path("/");
};


}]);
```

**Directed TemplateURL (Add Sales page)** - So when I click on save or cancel, neither of it redirects me back to the main page

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**Add Sales Controller**

```
app.controller('addController', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'salesService',
                              function($scope, $location, $routeParams, salesService){
$scope.save = function()
{
    salesService.addSales({id: $scope.Item.id, item: $scope.Item.item, name: $scope.Item.name, date: $scope.Item.date, price: $scope.Item.price});
    $location.path('/');
};

$scope.cancel = function()
{

    alert("deleted item asdasd");
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $location.path('/');
    });
};
}]);
```

Comment: Check your console for errors. If no error, post a plunkr reproducing the problem. Side not, why don't you just use `<a href="...">` for your links?

Comment: plunker made it worst since everything doesnt show (?), not sure if this is an error on my end (https://plnkr.co/edit/AToS79LLSVfo5li65awo?p=preview), checked thrice. if I use <a href> there wouldnt be a need for routing.

Comment: Once you remove all the useless jquery and bootstrap JS, once you put the correct location for angular.js, once you remove the section using an undefined dateTimeController, and once you remove the useless $scope.$apply() from the cancel() function, everything works fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/Lthey4J7n0DXUVWaeAkE?p=preview. A link with href points to a URL, that is mapped to a route. When clicking on a link with a href pointing at a URL, angular sets the location to that url, the router detects the location change, navigates to the route mapped to this url.

Comment: @JBNizet wow, it works now, thanks!! wished I could upvote your answer

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the `html5mode` property on `$locationProvider` to `true`.